# swifty way of doing if else

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbie in swift and I smell a bad code in the following logic

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let dest = segue.destination as? VC1,
        let index =  collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first{
        dest.selection = self.cellLabels[index.row]
    }
    if let dest2 = segue.destination as? VC2,
        let index2 =  collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first{
        dest2.selection = self.cellLabels[index2.row]
    }
    if let dest3 = segue.destination as? VC3,
        let index3 =  collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first{
        dest3.selection = self.cellLabels[index3.row]
    }

}
```

Essentially, I have multiple view controllers which I am trying to reach to depending on which Cell is tapped to.

Why I feel this is  bad code is because there is a lot of code repeation. 
Is there a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd define protocol:

```
protocol YourProtocolName: class {
    var selection: String? { get set }  // obviously, use whatever type that is appropriate in your case
}
```

Have your three view controller classes conform to that protocol, e.g.:

```
class VC1: UIViewController, YourProtocolName {
    var selection: String?

    ...
}
```

And then:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let dest = segue.destination as? YourProtocolName,
        let index =  collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
        dest.selection = cellLabels[index.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Following the [non-official AppIe guidelines on protocols](https://www.skilled.io/u/gregheo/what-the-55-swift-standard-library-protocols-taught-me) talk by Greg Heo. It might be better to change `HasSelection` to `Selectable`. See [2:30](https://youtu.be/_kpYI6GjCuw?t=151) to [7:15](https://youtu.be/_kpYI6GjCuw?t=434)

Comment: `Selectable` implies that the conforming type can be selected, but the VC itself cannot be.

Comment: @Honey - I agree that `Has` prefix is not good (there's a great article that I once stumbled across that describes the problems with that pattern; but I can't lay my hands on it right now). But if we're going to talk guidelines, the [official Apple guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#protocols-describing-what-is-should-read-as-nouns) advise that the able suffix (and ible and ing) should be used to describe a capability of the class and, as BallpointBen points out, Selectable suggests that it can be "selected", which is not the case here.

Comment: The entire purpose of the protocol is to label objects as having a particular property. Naming it `HasSelection` (or even `HasSelectionProperty`) perfectly describes what it is for. I'd go with a good description over rigid adherence to dogmatic guidlelines any day.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to follow the -`able` pattern, one could use `Selectionable`, but that's awful. I'd use `HasSelection` or `SelectionProtocol` before I went there. Even better, I'd prefer something that describes the utility of the protocol and some functional purpose, e.g. if these view controllers are for drilling into details, maybe `Detailing` or something like that. But I just didn't know what these view controllers did, so I refrained from going there. The idea was to describe the protocol pattern, not to open debates regarding naming conventions.

Comment: Thank for the link...I like your protocol idea. Just that when is a good idea to create a protocol like this? Does it make sense that just for this one reason we create a protocol?

Comment: You can create protocol for just this property, if that’s all you need. But more likely than not, there are other common behaviors that might belong in the protocol, too. This particular example is too ambiguous to be more specific, though. But it’s unlikely that the property is not the only common behavior/interfaces that you need.

Answer (score 4):

```
guard let index = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else { return }
switch segue.destination {
case let dest1 as VC1: dest1.selection = cellLabels[index.row]
case let dest2 as VC2: dest2.selection = cellLabels[index.row]
case let dest3 as VC3: dest3.selection = cellLabels[index.row]
}
```

Comment: If you change VC1, VC2, and VC3 to conform to a **protocol**, which has the `selection` property, then you only have to check for one type, instead of three.

Comment: This is an excellent solution if the actions for each case are different.  In this question, however, the actions are identical, so Rob's protocol-based solution is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it using parent class for all three ViewController classes and place the shared variables in the parent class. e.g.

```
class ParentViewControllerClass: UIViewController{
    var selection: Int?
}

class VC1: ParentViewControllerClass{
}
class VC2: ParentViewControllerClass{
}
class VC3: ParentViewControllerClass{
}
```

and then you should be able to assign value once. Like:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let dest = segue.destination as? ParentViewControllerClass, 
let index = collectionView?.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
  dest.selection = index
}
```

This way no matter which of three child view controllers is called the statement will be satisfied

Comment: One big flaw with this answer is you must assume that all 3 VC are `UIViewController`s, and not another class.  Using protocols is the better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: yeah, you're right. But I for some reason was assuming they all are simplu ViewControllers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath))
}
```